# Elimanating zero decimals from Computed Fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have the computed field in TSQl which computed size field but how can i get ride of Zero from decimals
forexample
RIM DIAMETER = 12.0
RIM WIDTH= 10.5

the computed field `SIZE`displayed as `12.0X10.50` i want the result to be displayed as `12X10.5`

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.[RIMS] ADD [SIZEtst] AS (

CASE 
WHEN CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), [RIM DIAMETER],0) IS NULL THEN ''
ELSE CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), [RIM DIAMETER],0)
end +
'X'+

CASE 
WHEN CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), [RIM WIDTH],0) IS NULL THEN ''
ELSE CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), [RIM WIDTH],0)
end
```

Comment: You can't use the same datatype and expect the output to be different like this. If your datatype has one decimal place it is going to have one decimal place always unless you force it string data. See the answer by John below, you can use his format example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Consider Format()**

```
Declare @D decimal(10,2) = 12.0
Declare @W decimal(10,2) = 10.5

Select concat(format(@D,'0.#'),'X',format(@W,'0.#'))
```

**Returns**

```
12X10.5
```

**Or the implicit conversion using float**

```
Declare @D float = 12.0
Declare @W float = 10.5

Select concat(@D,'X',@W)
```

This was intended as a demonstration of format function and/or the implicit conversion

```
    [SizeTst]  AS (concat(CONVERT([float],[RIM Diameter]),'X',CONVERT([float],[RIM Width])))

or

    [SizeTst]  AS (concat(format([RIM Diameter],'0.#'),'X',format([RIM Width],'0.#')))
```

Comment: John I am trying to create a computed field how can i update this `CONVERT (VARCHAR(50), [RIM DIAMETER],0)`

Comment: It's the same :). `ALTER TABLE dbo.[RIMS] ADD [SIZEtst] AS (concat([RIM DIAMETER],'X',[RIM WIDTH]))`

Comment: @Deadsheep39 still gives me 12.0X10.50 for RIM DIAMETER 12.0 and WIDTH 10.50 i want to eliminate the zeros i want to see 12X10.5

Comment: @KAKA it was intended as an illustration of the format function and/or the  implicit conversion   see update

Comment: @KAKA look at the format option. The good news for you is that John formatted this so that it will be 12X10.5 but will also support 13.6X11

Comment: Thanks  @JohnCappelletti @Sean, works perfect. what is `#` telling me?

Comment: @KAKA the # indicates optional or zero suppress.   If you had 0.000 there will be 3 decimal places

Comment: It is the format string. You really need to read up on things like this so you know what the code is doing. Become familiar with BOL (books online). Here is the documentation for format. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: @KAKA try Select format(100.25,'#.000'),format(100.25,'#.##'),format(100.25,'#.#'),format(100.25,'#')

Answer (score -1):

-- you can define table like this

```
create table [RIMS](
[RIM DIAMETER] float,
[RIM WIDTH] float
)
```

Comment: The OP is trying to create a computed column, not a table.

Comment: IS if he define his table like me format. his sql run is correct.

Comment: You didn't explain that at all. And floats can be problematic because they don't always return the value you think they should because they are an approximate datatype.